# How big was the kapa trade out of Hawaii?

Tags: trade

The production of [kapa bark cloth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapa) was a major industry in premodern Hawaii.  Once Hawaii was opened to the outside world (1778 and onwards), was kapa exported from Hawaii?  Was it a significant trade good, or was it simply a curiosity?

Wikipedia says (at present):

> After the European discovery of the Hawaiian Islands, Western traders travelled to Hawaiʻi especially for kapa.

but there's no source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Center for Labor Education & Research website of University of Hawai‘i](http://clear.uhwo.hawaii.edu/Lhistory.html), it mentions that it was for as currency:

> With the arrival of Western traders and businessmen, native Hawaiian
>   resources like kapa bark cloth and the highly prized and fragrant
>   ‘iliahi, sandalwood, soon became the currency supporting a new island
>   economy. By 1827, though, the reigning monarch, King Kamehameha III
>   was faced with a burgeoning trade deficit and many personal debts. To
>   meet this crisis he was forced to decree that every man would be
>   assessed a picul of sandalwood and every woman, not infirm or
>   decrepit, a 12 feet by six feet kapa mat.
>
> At his command loyal maka‘āinana laboriously depleted the aged
>   sandalwood forests to such an extent that this slow-growing tree was
>   nearly eradicated. As the sandalwood trade exhausted, it was soon
>   replaced by the demands of the whaling industry. Sailors wanted fresh
>   vegetables, sturdy kapa for ship repair, and young, able-bodied men to
>   fill out their crews.

So based on this authority I would not say it was merely a 'curiosity'. [Further reading here](http://www.kapahawaii.com/polynesia-tapa-diffirences.html).

and [here](http://www.coffeetimes.com/kapa2.htm).

Comment: To clarify, tapa cloth was used for patching sails - not as durable as canvas, but it's hard to find cotton in the middle of the Pacific. Trying to run down an online source for this now...